# How to design a line deleting function for Tetris game?

Tags: javascript, html, tetris

I am trying to build a Tetris game in javaScript and HTML. I ran into problems with my function for removing the full lines. It sort of works, but not every time and not as I expected. I am not a professional programmer, I am learning to code just for fun. My knowledge of javaScript is limited and my methods are primitive. My board is made of div tags. Each of them represents one square and has an id with unique number. Currently falling shape is stored by an array called “brick”. It contains four numbers, which corresponds to the div ids.

For example brick = [2, 2, 3, 5] means Tetris “l” piece positioned horizontally. There are 12 squares in a row. The first and last has the class “fender,” which means, that they cannot became part of the brick, and so the shape could not leave the board.

The fender squares are made invisible by CSS. The brick is falling by adding 12. From [2, 3, 4, 5] it is [14, 15, 16, 17], etc. The first four rows have display set to “none,” so the visible board starts by square number 63.

On the beginning, every square of the board (except the fender squares)  has a class “free,” which means that it is permeable for falling shape. When it does not have the class, the shape can’t move through it. When the brick hits the bottom or another fallen shape, it is added to another variable, called pile.

This is done by a function called touchdown(). It does several other things. The color of the brick is stored in another variable called colorPile. For example when the blue brick [2, 3, 4, 5] lands, it adds to colorPile variable four times “blue”. Touchdown() also  removes the class “free” from all the squares of the brick, so the next brick can’t fall through the occupied space. Then it calls for the creation of a new brick.

The deleting process starts with function called testLines():

```
      // Look through all board lines 
   for (var i = 62; i < 300; i += 12) {
       // Prepare empty array 
       line = [];
       // Put numbers of occupied squares in the array.
       for (var j = i; j < i + 10; j++) {
           if (document.getElementById("sq" + j).classList.contains("free") === false) {
               line.push(j);
           }
       }
       // When the line is full, put its number in “numb” variable and call for deleting function  
       if (line.length == 10) {
           numb = i;
           clearLine(numb);
       }
   }
   }
   }
```

It goes through all lines of the board and look for the full ones. If there is a full line, it stores its number in a variable called “numb” and calls another function named clearLine():

```
function clearLine() {
// Put the indexes of the squares in the full line in a special array
indexes = [];
for (var i = numb; i < numb + 10; i++) {
    indexes.push(pile.indexOf(i));
}
// Remove numbers on the indexes
pileindexor = indexes.length;
while (pileindexor--) {
    pile.splice(indexes[pileindexor], 1);
}
// Add 12 to all numbers greater than the line number (= move them on row down)
for (var j = 0; j < pile.length; j++) {
    if (pile[j] < numb) {
        pile[j] = (pile[j] + 12);
    }
}
clearColorPile();
paintPile();
clearBoard();
lines++;
testLines();
```

}

It also calls function called clearColorPile(), which removes colors on same indexes from the "colorPile" variable. Next it calls another function called paintPile(). The paintPile() function changes color of all squares in the "pile" variable according to the modified "colorPile" variable and removes “free” class from them.

Than the clearLine() calls another function called clearBoard(). It paints all squares not belonging to the pile white and ads the “free” class to them. Finally, the clearLine() function calls again the  testLines() to look for more full rows.

This procedure is behaving as I expected for most of the time. But sometimes, the full line is not cleared completely. My game is [here](https://codepen.io/radekjohn/pen/eebbNP). You can see for yourselves. What have I done wrong? How to delete the full line?

Comment: If you are really interested in programming for fun, I suggest taking a free online class or reading some in-depth tutorials.

Comment: Well, I am doing so. I even started to read some tutorial how to make a Tetris game. It said something like “If you want a real challenge, do not read this tutorial and try to create the game without it.” So I am trying.

Comment: When I come across such puzzles, I make a best attempt to not read the tutorial until I get stuck. Then I start reading the tutorial looking for the part that I think will help me the most.  Then when I'm done, I might even read the whole tutorial to see how much in common our solutions are.  Otherwise, I'd ask the very simple question, "Why even start reading the tutorial if the tutorial tells me not to read it?"

Comment: Yes, that’s probably the best general approach.

Comment: the arrow keys don't even work in your demo :/

Comment: They are working on my computer now . I was changing something.

Comment: (But not with arrow keys.)